# Prime factorization in prolog

Tags: prolog, primes, number-theory

I'm new to Prolog. I read this code which finds prime factors of an integer:

```
factors(1,[1]) :-
   true, !.
factors(X,[Factor1|T]) :-
   X > 0,
   between(2,X,Factor1), 
   NewX is X // Factor1, (X mod Factor1) =:= 0,
   factors(NewX,T), !.
```

And changed it to this one:

```
factors(1,[[1,1]]) :-
   true, !.
factors(X,[Factor1|T]) :-
   X > 0,
   (  is_list(Factor1),
      length(Factor1, 2),
      Factor1 = [Base|A],
      A = [Pow], 
      between(2,X,Base),
      between(1,100,Pow), 
      NewX is X / (Base ** Pow),
      (X mod Base) =:= 0,
      (NewX mod Base) =\= 0
   ),
   factors(NewX,T), !.
```

Well the first one works perfect, but the latter doesn't respond to queries. i.e. when I enter:

```
factors(2,[[2,1],[1,1]]).
```

I get 'true', but when I enter:

```
factors(2,X).
```

I get 'false'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Base` and `Pow` aren't bound to anything yet (they are parts of the `X` that you pass), you can't compute `NewX` (and the `between`s might not work, either).

Comment: The `between/2` statements bound concrete values to `Base` and `Pow`, so `NewX` can be computed (if there weren't the problem with `is_list/2`). If they weren't bound, `is/2` would raise an exception.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter `factors(2,X)`, `Factor1` is not bound and `is_list(Factor1)` fails.

I think your code

```
is_list(Factor1),
length(Factor1, 2),
Factor1 = [Base|A],
A = [Pow]
```

can be abbreviated to `Factor1 = [Base,Pow]`. Since `Factor1` is not used anywhere else, you can move `[Base,Pow]` into the head of the clause.

You can omit `true`, it has no effect here. The parenthesis haven't any effect, neither. So your code could be written as:

```
factors(1,[[1,1]]) :- !.
factors(X,[[Base,Pow]|T]) :-
   X > 0,
   between(2,X,Base),
   between(1,100,Pow), 
   NewX is X / (Base ** Pow),
   (X mod Base) =:= 0,
   (NewX mod Base) =\= 0,
   factors(NewX,T), !.
```

On my system (using SICStus), one must use

```
NewX is X // floor(Base ** Pow)
```

to prevent that `NewX` becomes a float which leads to an error when passed to `mod` as argument.

**Edit**: I originally wrote that the last cut had no effect. That is not true because `between/2` creates choice points. I removed that part of my answer and put the cut back into the code.

Comment: we should also point out how terrible this algorithm is, computationally.